# Unix commands using grep to specify a pattern

Tags: unix, grep, command

I have a file named `LastNames.txt` that lists 100 last names with percentage of popularity from 0 to 100.
The question is how to use `grep` to create new file that contains last names with `0.000` percent popularity only.
Note: I use Unix commands and this is the code I used:

```
grep '0.000' LastNames.tab > unpopularNames.tab
```

When I use this command I get some last names with greater percentage than 0.000.

Comment: Better gives sample input/output here

Comment: input: grep '0.000' LastNames.tab > unpopularNames.tab 
output: 
PEACE    0.003
GAGLIARDI    0.001
ZUPAN    0.000
ZUCHOWSKI    0.000

Comment: @user2066595 - sputnik meant update your question with formatted sample input and formatted expected output, not add a comment with unformatted, undesirable output.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this :

```
 grep '\b0\.000\b' LastNames
```

- the dot `.` mean *any character* in [regex](/questions/tagged/regex)
- `\.` mean a *literal* `.`
- `\b` means *word boundaries*

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to try to make grep do an RE comparison when what you really want is an arithmetic comparison:

```
$ cat file
PEACE 0.003
GAGLIARDI 0.001
ZUPAN 0.000
ZUCHOWSKI 0.000

$ awk '$NF == 0' file
ZUPAN 0.000
ZUCHOWSKI 0.000
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the `-F` and `-w` flags to do a fixed string match on whole words:

```bsh
grep -Fw 0.000 file
```

From man `grep`:

> -F, --fixed-strings
>
> Interpret  PATTERN  as  a  list  of  fixed strings, separated by
>                 newlines, any of which is to be matched.  (-F  is  specified  by
>                 POSIX.)
>
> -w, --word-regexp
>
> Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole
>                 words.  The test is that the matching substring must  either  be
>                 at  the  beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded  by  a non-word
>                 constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the  end
>                 of  the  line  or  followed by a non-word constituent character.
>                 Word-constituent  characters  are  letters,  digits,   and   the
>                 underscore.

Demo:

```bsh
$ cat file
error      0E000
top      100.000
middle    50.000
lower     25.000
bottom     0.000

# Orignal over matching grep 
$ grep 0.000 file
error      0E000
top      100.000
middle    50.000
bottom     0.000

# With correct flags only right lines are matched
$ grep -Fw 0.000 file
bottom     0.000
```

Note: You could use `fgrep` instead of `grep -F`:

```bsh
fgrep -w 0.000 file
```